# Unable to override exchange name while subscribing in RabbitMq using Masstransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I would like to create a Subscriber that listens to existing exchange and queues bound to that exchange using MassTransit and RabbitMq.
Environment Details:
dotnet version : 4.8
MassTransit version : 7.1.3

Please find my subscriber code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Contracts;
using MassTransit;

namespace Subscriber
{
    internal class Receive
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new RabbitMqConfig
            {
                ConnectionString = "rabbitmq://localhost",
                TopicExchange = "manualexchange",
                QueueSubscription = "manualqueue",
                TimeOutInMinutes = 1,
                UserName = "guest",
                Password = "guest"
            };

            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri(config.ConnectionString), h =>
                {
                    h.Username(config.UserName);
                    h.Password(config.Password);
                });

                //TODO : override masstransit topic name and use given configuration


                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(config.QueueSubscription, e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    e.Consumer(() => new ValueConsumer());
                    e.Bind(config.TopicExchange);
                });

            });
            await bus.StartAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            await bus.StopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the exchanges and queues present before starting consumer :
[image]
[image]

After creating instance of consumer, a new exchange with name as the queue is created and the bindings are redirected. Since the old exchange is used by other publishers, all the messages that come to old exchange are moved to _skipped queue. How can I override the exchange name of the consumer using MassTransit?
I referred https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/publish.html but it will be helpful if there is any sample code to understand how to override the exchange and queue while creating a consumer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The topology used with RabbitMQ is [explained in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/rabbitmq.html#broker-topology).

An exchange, matching the queue name, is always created. Bindings are made to that exchange, and not to the queue directly.

It's also covered in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNpXjy7psxs).